# OpenCV warpperspective cuts off left and top in video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have found a homography matrix successfully that finds the difference between frames of a video for stabilization. I am using the warpperspective function to warp each frame, but the top and left portions are cut off. I think this is because the pixels would go to a negative location in the image, but I am not sure how to fix this without affecting the stabilization.

In the code below I make the image twice the size and move it to the centre so that it has room to move without being cut off. This works fine for the bottom and right sides.

Is there a way to keep the entire image?

```py
frame = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, m, (320*2, 240*2))
dst = dst = np.float32([[1,0,160],[0,1,120]]) 
frame = cv2.warpAffine(frame,dst,(320*2,240*2))
```

The input frame looks like this:

[image]

The output frame looks like this:

[image]

A lot of the table on the left is cut off and I am wondering how to get this part to show up. Thanks

Comment: Please show your input and output images. It is hard to answer out of context. You should also show your full code. It is likely the output is clipped to the size of the input. You may need to back project the input corners to the output to get the full size needed for the output image.

Comment: I have added some images to show you what I mean, there is a lot of other things in the code so it would make it pretty long to show. Also not sure what help it would be as I basically just load in a video and show it frame by frame changing it with the code shown